# jquery onclick event doesn't work

Tags: jquery, events, onclick

This script doesn't work.. Where is the error? 
With .onload it's OK

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var img = new Image();
img.onClick = function() {
$("div").animate({width:this.width, height:this.height});
}
img.src = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif';
});
```

thanks for the aid.

Comment: this has nothing to do with Java

Comment: What exactly "does not work"? What has to happen that you can say that it works? There is no JS error at least...

Comment: @migg http://jsfiddle.net/gphp/CHuBx/5/

Comment: @Giovanni So the script does something, but please explain what you are trying to achieve and what is not working. Until then it is only guesswork. A script without requirements always works as long as it does not produce runtime errors.

Comment: sorry for bad english..
this is my situation http://jsfiddle.net/gphp/CHuBx/6/
i have a div with 100px height and width with a image background. when i click on div i would like the div change dimension with the image dimension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its `.onclick` not `.onClick`, javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: @Giovanni How do you know it doesn't work if you don't add the image to the document? http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/CHuBx/1/

Comment: i don't have the image in the document, only url.
with onload it's work http://jsfiddle.net/gphp/CHuBx/3/

Comment: How can you click the image if it's not in the document?

Comment: @Giovanni you have to attach the click handler to the div to accomplish what you want http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/CHuBx/7/

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery anyway, why not just stick with it:

```
$(function(){  // this is a shortcut for $(document).ready
   var img = $('<img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif>');
   img.on('click', function(){
     $('div').animate(...)
   })
   img.appendTo('body')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif';

$(img).live("click", function() {
    $("div").animate({
        width: $(this).width(),
        height: $(this).height()
    }, 1000);
}).appendTo('body');​
```